# Taylor's Theorem and Newton's Method of Divided Differences

Tags: mathematics, calculus

While reading Chandrashrkhar's edition of Principia , I came to know that *Newton's Method of Divided Differences can be used to prove Taylor's Theorem. Could some one help me in knowing how this is possible.* I found this http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037704279900360X but it didn't help .

**Edit**

Note- I want this

**Could someone give a reference to a book or a link where I can study the method of divided differences in sense in which Newton developed it**

Comment: This is sketched in Problem 20.4 of my history of mathematics course notes: http://intellectualmathematics.com/history-of-mathematics/

Comment: @ViktorBlasjo  Thanks its a great article. Not only Newton but Kepler too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not only can it be done, it is how Taylor did it: [B. Taylor, *Methodus incrementorum directa et inversa* (1715), 21--23,
 Prop. VII Theor. III & Coroll. II.](https://books.google.com/books?id=r-Gq9YyZYXYC&pg=PA21).

Taylor developed Taylor series through uniformly spaced nodes at $t_j=t_0+j\,\Delta t$, interpolating $x=x(t)$ between $t_0$ (Taylor uses $z$ equally for $t$ and $t_0$) and $t_0+v$, for some increment $v$ in $n$ steps. From Newton's interpolation formula, Taylor derived the formula (Prop. VII)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {(t-t_0) \strut\over\strut 1}{(t-t_0-\Delta t) \strut\over\strut 2}
  {(t-t_0-2\Delta t) \strut\over\strut 3}\cdots{(t-t_0-(k-1)\Delta t) \strut\over\strut k}
  {\Delta^k x \over \Delta t^k}\,.
$$
He wrote the proposition in terms of forward differences, but it is, of course, equivalent to divided differences.

Letting $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ (*Si pro Incrementis evanescentibus scribantur fluxiones...*), 
Taylor obtained that ${\Delta^k y / \Delta t^k} \rightarrow {d^ky /dt^k}$ and the other factors approach $(t-t_0)^k/k!$, which yields the Taylor series, since $n$ is determined by $v$ and $\Delta t$.
Klein called it a "a limit-taking of unheard-of boldness"
(*"Hierin liegt nun tatsächlich Grenzübergang von unerhörter Kühnheit"*), 
*Elementarmathematik vom höheren Standpunkte aus: Arithmetik, Algebra, Analysis* (1908).